# Python - selenium - AngularJS drop downs, how to click them?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am scraping his website. To create an account. Below is the url

https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGnewUI/Search/Home/Home?partnerid=25222&siteid=5011&noback=1&fromSM=true#CreateAccount

After going to this site, click on `"Dont have an account yet?"` and click `"Agree"` on the next page.

There I have security questions to fill. For that I wrote the below script.

```
def findxpath_AddKey(xpath, key1, id, key2):
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    element.click()
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-activedescendant',{})".format(key1),element)
    span = browser.find_element_by_id(id)
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = {}".format(key2), span)
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class',\"ui-selectmenu-button ui-button ui-widget ui-selectmenu-button-closed ui-corner-all\")",element)

findxpath_AddKey('//*[@id="selectSecurityQuestion1-button"]',"'ui-id-3'", 'selectSecurityQuestion1-button_text', "'Where is your favorite vacation spot?'")
```

Above process is repeated for other security questions and click `"continue"`. But the website is throwing errors, saying that to fill security questions.

[image: The error in the page]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem or not, but I *do* know that, sometimes, manually editing the inner text of a form will not register as a form being filled out—and that's what I believe you're doing by using `setAttribute`.

Instead of `setAttribute`, try using the driver's `send_keys` method. It would look something like this:

```
form_field = browser.find_element_by_id('ID_OF_FORM_FIELD')
form_field.send_keys('Answer to security question')
```

You don't have to use the `id` to find the field, either. You could use `find_element_by_xpath` or whatever other identifier you can think of.